# Вопрос по виджетам YII

Tags: php, yii, виджет

Код вызова виджета наподобие этого находится во вью.
`$this->widget('application.components.weather.GoogleWeatherAPI', array('location'=>$location));`

Вопрос. Откуда передается $location? Из контроллера?

Comment: Ваш виджет 2009 года. Кроме того, сервиса GoogleWeatherAPI [уже нет в живых](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150572/). Аминь

Comment: Я же сказал "наподобие", а не "конкретно этот". Виджет меня вообще не волнует. Меня волнует откуда ему передается параметр.

Comment: `откуда ему передается параметр` С потолка. Сами задаёте.

Comment: Кроме того, если взять именно этот виджет и посмотреть в его исходники, то можно заметить, что если `location` не задавать, то значение по умолчанию будет `63371`

Comment: Мне еще раз повторить, что конкретно этот виджет меня не волнует, а код взят для примера? Впрочем, ниже уже ответ есть. Спасибо, что уделили мне время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, переменные в отображение передаются с контроллера

```
public function weatherAction()
{
    $location = [123456789, 123456789];

    // тут рендериться отображение, в котором будет осуществлен вызов виджета
    $this->render('weather', [
        // в этом массиве передаем переменные 
        // которые будут доступны в отображении
        'location' => $location
    ]);
}
```